# How to set JVM stack size in Grails BuildConfig

Tags: grails, jvm-arguments

I have a Grails 2.3.X project which fails to compile unless given more stack size with `-Xss1024k` command line argument. At the moment this works fine, but requires me to export/set the JVM option each time I build the project for the first time. Also, developers starting out freshly in the project will stumble on this always, so I'd like it to be part of the code checked out of version control.

**Is there a way to set stacksize(-Xss) JVM option in Grails 2.3.X BuildConfig?**

P.S. The -Xss JVM option is one of the less documented ones. I found it only through [internet archives](http://web.archive.org/web/20110430195227/http://blogs.sun.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html) linked here in StackOverflow

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: @Joshua, I updated the question to contain version information

Comment: Are you using forked execution? If so, then you can pass JVM arguments as a map. According to the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode

Comment: @Joshua, unfortunately that does not help. I'm not sure if the forked mode even works on Windows. Great suggestion, though.

Comment: I can confirm that forked mode works just fine on Windows. I am running it right now. Otherwise there isn't a way to specify JVM args to run-app via BuildConfig.groovy. The only other suggestion is to make a custom Gant script which has them inside there for your devs. Obviously that script would be a part of the project and in source control.

Comment: I double checked my confs and noticed I was editing the wrong line. In order to get this working, I had to add a new line at the config stating `grails.project.fork.compile.jvmArgs = [ '-Xss1024k' ]`. Adding jvmArgs to the end of the list did not work. @Joshua, if you'll kindly add your recommendations as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Grails 2.3 you can use [forked execution](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode). In your case you can pass the additional arguments as such:

```
grails.project.fork.compile.jvmArgs = [ '-Xss1024k' ]
```

Comment: What with grails 1.3.7 vesrion.  I tried this `grails run-app GRAILS_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` is it correct. How to incease heap size.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass all JVM args in BuildConfig.groovy as a closure:

```
grails {
    tomcat {
        jvmArgs = ["-server", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m", "-XX:MaxNewSize=512m", "-XX:NewSize=512m",
                "-Xms2048m", "-Xmx2048m", "-XX:SurvivorRatio=128", "-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0",
                "-XX:+UseTLAB", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled",
                "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode", "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit", "-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent"]
    }
```